# How can I deactivate CR only if its effect is to move to the next line?

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, events

I don't use arrow keys, but to avoid the cursor moving should I hit them by mistake, I have this in my vimrc:

```
inoremap <Left>      <NOP>
inoremap <Right>     <NOP>
inoremap <Up>        <NOP>
inoremap <Down>      <NOP>
noremap  <Left>      <NOP>
noremap  <Right>     <NOP>
noremap  <Up>        <NOP>
noremap  <Down>      <NOP>
```

I also don't like the idea of hitting `ZZ` or `ZQ` in normal mode by mistake, so I also have

```
nnoremap ZZ          <NOP>
nnoremap ZQ          <NOP>
```

And what about `:help` opening if I mistakenly hith <kbd>F1</kbd>?

```
noremap  <F1>        <NOP>
lnoremap <F1>        <NOP>
tnoremap <F1>        <NOP>
```

Eventually I ended up adding the following too

```cpp
nnoremap <CR>        <NOP>
```

but soon discovered that was not a good idea, as I couldn't use <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the command window anymore. So I added

```
augroup NormalModeCarriageReturnIsNoOpExceptInCmdwin
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdwinEnter * nunmap <CR>
  autocmd CmdwinLeave * nnoremap <CR> <NOP>
augroup END
```

but doing some code navigation I've also noticed another place where I need <kbd>Enter</kbd> to keep its original meaning is in quickfix windows. However there's no such event as `QuickfixWinEnter`/`QuickfixWinLeave`.

So the question is: how can I deactivate <kbd>Enter</kbd> only when its effect would be the same as <kbd>j</kbd> (well, not exactly the *same*, but I don't care about their little difference)?

Answer (score 1):

Using an expression mapping is probably the easiest here:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <CR> &ft == 'qf' \|\| getcmdwintype() != '' ? '<CR>' : ''
```

If the filetype is `qf` or `getcmdwintype()` is not empty then the current context is the quickfix window or commandline window, so we return a `<CR>`, and if it's anything else we return an empty string which is identical to `<NOP>`.